# R ggplot2: remove panel spacing from strip text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot with two x-axis (grouped x-axis):

```
# read data 
tmp <- read.table(text = "label CNV_x   CNV_Type
17p -1  Loss
                  9p    -1  Loss
                  16q   1   Gain
                  10p   1   Gain
                  8q    1   Gain
                  13q   1   Gain", header = T)
tmp$CNV_Type <- relevel(tmp$CNV_Type, ref = 'Loss')

# plot
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = label, y = CNV_x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~CNV_Type, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA))
```

This creates a plot like this:

[image]

This plot shows `0.00` twice on x-axis and I can't figure out a way to remove the spacing between the two vertical lines separating the strips (one is `Gain` and other is `Loss`).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I added `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` as suggested below:

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = label, y = CNV_x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~CNV_Type, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA))
```

This creates a plot like this:

[image]

The only issue now is there is no spacing between the bars and the left and right margins of the plot - not sure why that happened.

Comment: The code may be reproducible, but all the extra styling makes it quite hard to read. I'd recommend cutting out as much superfluous code as possible

Comment: Try adding `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))`

Comment: @MikeyHarper I just added that line before coord flip but instead of scale_x_continuous I used scale_y_continuous. It removes the double vertical lines but now there is no space at the end of the bars. I will update my post with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use facets here. A couple of options. You could indicate the type by colour:

```
tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(label, CNV_x)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = CNV_Type)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "skyblue3"))
```

[image]

And/or add the labels for type to the plot using `annotate`. That requires some manual fiddling with x, y and expand to get it right:

```
tmp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(label, CNV_x)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  annotate("text", 
           label = c("Loss", "Gain"), 
           x = c(7, 7), 
           y = c(-0.5, 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot color the bars because the figures are needed in grayscale. I'll give annotate a try. Thanks!